# FetchResultsController displaying no sections

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason, the code below is producing weird output.

```
#define INITIAL_BATCH_SIZE 500

// Initializes the NSFetchedResultsController to the following request
- (void)initializeFetchResultsController
{
    // Makes a request for the given entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tweet"];
    request.predicate = nil;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp"
                                                              ascending:NO]];
    request.fetchBatchSize = INITIAL_BATCH_SIZE;

    NSArray *matches = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%d", [matches count]);

    // Creates a fetchedResultsController
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
}
```

When I print out `matches count` I get 144192, however when I print out the number of sections in the `self.fetchedResultsController` I get 0 using the code below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"Sections: %d", [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

I had initialized the code in view did load and during debugging I noticed that `self.fetchedResultsController` was initialized so the problem does not deal with an initialized `self.fetchedResultsController`.

I am trying to find out the reason for this but cannot. For more information, I have a UIViewController that contains a tableview in which I hooked up its delegate and datasource but I don't think that there is any problem with that which is causing this issue.

Comment: When executing your fetch request, you're passing in NULL. Why don't you pass in an error and make sure there isn't an error there to start?

Comment: The error is NULL when I printed it out. It should be because we got actually got an array back from the fetch request.

Comment: You need to call a NSFetchedResultsController's performFetch method to actually fetch data.

Comment: @sidslog You sir are the best. I can't believe I forgot this.